# Get data of a dynamic header from a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table `Table1` connected to an external workbook by Power Query. So the headers and the data of the table may change.

I understand that, if `H1` is a header of `Table1`, the formula `=Table1[H1]` could return all the data of `H1`.

Now, in Cell A1, I write a possible header name. In Cell B1, I'm looking for a formula to automatically return the data of the header written in A1. Does anyone know if there is an easy formula to do so?

Comment: Have you try Index Match or Filter function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to look for the *header name* - not the column - then you have to extend P.b. answer:
`=INDEX(Table1;;MATCH(A1;Table1[#Headers];0))`

Answer (score 1):

`=INDEX(Table1[#All],,1)` change `1` to the correct column number of your table.

Office 365 will spill all data from that column including header.